# Facing issue scaling up akka-http server

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have an sbt project: with versions:

```
Versions of akka-actor, akka-stream = 2.4.17
Versions of akka-http-core and akka-http = 10.0.4
```

This is How I start the server:

```
system = ActorSystem("my-server", conf)
mat = ActorMaterializer.create(system)
ec = system.dispatcher

httpService = Http().bindAndHandle(routeWithTypeAndLogging(routeType), bindHost, bindPort)
```

I have written an API which has only sleep between 30 to 60 ms, which I hit from `jmeter` to find out: how much concurrency I can hit the API, without client facing higher throughput. API is deployed on a 20 core, 34G machine. API looks like following:

```
get {
  parameters('dummy') { dummy =>
  complete{
    Future {
    Thread.sleep(30 + randomGenerator.nextInt(30))
    GenericResponse(200, Map(), Response("Success"))
  }(ioDispatcher)
  }
  }
}
```

When I hit this API, with 200 threads from jmeter: I get following response:

```
summary +  88512 in 00:00:25 = 3522.2/s Avg:    55 Min:    30 Max:  1547 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary =  88513 in 00:00:25 = 3485.3/s Avg:    55 Min:    30 Max:  1547 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary + 106546 in 00:00:30 = 3551.5/s Avg:    55 Min:    30 Max:   904 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary = 195059 in 00:00:55 = 3521.2/s Avg:    55 Min:    30 Max:  1547 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary + 106825 in 00:00:30 = 3560.8/s Avg:    55 Min:    30 Max:  1127 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary = 301884 in 00:01:25 = 3535.1/s Avg:    55 Min:    30 Max:  1547 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

But when I hit from 3 different machines with 200 threads each(total 600 threads): I get following response:

```
summary =  98338 in 00:01:22 = 1203.3/s Avg:   163 Min:    30 Max: 10022 Err:    70 (0.07%)
summary +  35672 in 00:00:30 = 1189.1/s Avg:   162 Min:    30 Max:  7944 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary = 134010 in 00:01:52 = 1199.5/s Avg:   163 Min:    30 Max: 10022 Err:    70 (0.05%)
summary +  35837 in 00:00:30 = 1194.6/s Avg:   173 Min:    30 Max:  9140 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary = 169847 in 00:02:22 = 1198.5/s Avg:   165 Min:    30 Max: 10022 Err:    70 (0.04%)
summary +  35024 in 00:00:30 = 1167.5/s Avg:   164 Min:    30 Max: 10040 Err:    69 (0.20%) Active: 200 Started: 200 Finished: 0
summary = 204871 in 00:02:52 = 1193.1/s Avg:   165 Min:    30 Max: 10040 Err:   139 (0.07%)
```

As you can see, on both cases, I am not able to get more than around 3600qps, but worrisome thing is With 600 threads hitting the server, It is degraded as well for client.

I have already given `akka.http.server.max-connections` to 8192 while changing `akka.http.server.pipelining-limit` have no impact on above results.

Updating akka-http to `10.0.11` also did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never ever ever use `Thread.sleep` with futures (at least without a proper ExecutorService)

To Await use `Scheduler.scheduleOnce` all together with `Promise` like (completely untested):

```
get {
  parameters('dummy') { dummy =>
    complete{
      val p = Promise[GenericResponse]()
      system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(50 milliseconds) {
        p success GenericResponse(200, Map(), Response("Success"))
      }
      p.future
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why Thread.sleep and Future don't go well together. In my actual code, there will be I/O calls like DB/kafka, etc, so I was just trying to simulate those I/O calls via Thread.sleep. Will test it with scheduler also but bot very sure which way is better to simulate I/O.

Comment: Futures works around fork-join which use a small thread pool. If you block a thread, then, in the best case scenario, the fork-join framework will create a few more for you, that is expensive to do at run time (worst case is a thread pool starvation issue). In addition, if you block you are missing the entire point of use an async approach (less threads = less context switch which is expensive). There is no problem to use I/O if you are using async drivers, Kafka and many databases have async drivers.

Comment: If you really need to block you will need to change your dispatcher:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/handling-blocking-operations-in-akka-http-routes.html
But I would rather suggest you to change the technology.

Comment: Thanks, using the scheduler, I was able to get around 15k qps, with better performance, I will look at my actual code and see what optimisation can be done as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Your Thread.sleep is making worst the performance. Time ago, I wrote a Akka-http server that you could configure the response´s delay. Using Futures, sending a message to one actor and using the akka after pattern to avoid stopping threads https://github.com/EmiCareOfCell44/http-retarder/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/ecocell44 . Check this out and you tell me if it improves your experiment.